# setup static route via dhcp

Tags: redhat, dhcp-option

I try to push static routes over dhcp in a redhat enviroment. 
I have already activatet the option rfc3442-classless-static-routes.
The dhcp client is also configured to request this optien as described in 
https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.1_Technical_Notes/ar01s04s05.html

My issue is that the dhcp.lease included my option i can see it here.

```
[root@pDb1 dhclient]# cat dhclient-eth0.leases
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 10.1.0.100;
  filename "/pxelinux.0";
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 10.1.0.3;
  option dhcp-lease-time 43200;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 10.1.0.240;
  option rfc3442-classless-static-routes 8,10,0,0,10,1,0,240;
  option host-name "pDb1";
  renew 1 2012/11/12 14:42:54;
  rebind 1 2012/11/12 19:43:30;
  expire 1 2012/11/12 21:13:30;
}
```

But it don't update the routing table.

```
[root@pDb1 dhclient]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.1.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
default         10.1.0.3        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```